# C# Application fails silently when exception is thrown

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

I've made a small winforms application that throws an exception on startup:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  throw new Exception("lol");
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

When I run this from the debugger an exception is thrown as I would expect. If I browse to the executable in the bin directory and run if from explorer then the app just fails silently without displaying even a 'This application has crashed dialog'.

I do get the exception logged in the Event Viewer:

```
Application: WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main()
```

but that's not exactly a great deal of help!

This happens for a bunch of apps, I feel like I have some system-wide setting that's suppressing this system dialog, but I have no idea what it might be! Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding a WinForms application only starts, when the

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

call is made. It does not have a console output, it will try to tell you everything through the WinForms UI. But at this point it does not have one.

If you want the application to display anything, you have to make sure the message loop is started. So if you want to throw an exception immediately when the application starts, override the OnLoad method of the form and throw the exception there. (I moved the code from Program.cs to the form's code-behind)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            throw new ApplicationException("ASDF");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //AllocConsole();
            //Console.WriteLine("BOOO");
            //throw new ApplicationException("BOOOO");
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

    }
}
```

This should present you with a "nice" exception window.

Or write a console application. :)

If you must, you can try to allocate a console output:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AllocConsole();
            Console.WriteLine("BOOO");
            throw new ApplicationException("BOOOO");
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();
    }
}
```

But IMHO letting the application start and then handling the issue on the UI it is supposed to use, would be the cleaner approach.

Comment: I just tried moving the exception to the OnLoad() function of the form, and got the same result (i.e. no notification that an exception had occurred when there's no debugger attached)

Comment: Interesting. I have added some more code for the overriding solution. It gives me an exception window. Please compare it to what you did.

Comment: Interesting. I had initially put the exception in the event handler for OnLoad, then I tried overriding OnLoad() as you did. No joy in either case. I have just tried instead putting the exception in a OnClick() handler for the form and that DID show the system dialog, so I think that your hunch about message queues etc is along the right lines...

Comment: The point is, you have to make sure that your UI is set up, so if you want to display the error before the windows forms applications starts up, you either have to use `MessageBox.Show()` or aquire a console output like with `AllocConsole`. But it is much better to not throw exceptions before the Windows message loop starts. Moreover handle the exceptions and present a proper UI explaining the issue, and do not rely on the one WinForms defaults to (that just gives the impression that your application is broken).

Comment: The key take home for me is to move all program code to after the UI is up. I had some initialisation in Program.Main() but I will move this elsewhere and (lazily?) initialise once the form is up. I appreciate that proper code should deal well with exceptions, but this is still in the early stages of development and I spent a long time trying to work out why it "just didn't work" when someone else tested it without even a clue that it was doing anything at all. I feel dirty wrapping every function in a try block just in case!

Answer (score 0):

Try handling appdomain unhandled excpetionevent.

```
  public static void Main()
  {
   AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
   currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
  }

  static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) 
  {
   Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
   Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
   Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", args.IsTerminating);
  }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did try this, but that didn't help unfortunately. It also seemed to generate it's own security exceptions when running from a ClickOnce start menu shortcut so I backed away from that as a further rabbit hole I didn't want to go down :)